# how do i clamp my camera's rotation on X and Y?

Tags: camera, rotate

i'm using a script to make my camera rotate smoothly toward the mouse cursor on the screen. and the only thing i need is to somehow clamp it's rotation on X and Y. here :

```
 public float Xspeed = 2.0f;
 public float Yspeed = 2.0f;
 private float yaw = 0.0f;
 private float pitch = 0.0f;
 public float minimumX = -20f;
 public float maximumX = 20f;
 public float minimumY = -45f;
 public float maximumY = 45f;
 public float damping = 2.0f;
 void Start()
 {

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     ///////// looking
     yaw += Xspeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
     pitch -= Yspeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
     
     var desiredRotQ = Quaternion.Euler(pitch, yaw, 0);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, desiredRotQ, 
    Time.deltaTime * damping);
 }
```

Comment: Presumably you tried Mathf.Clamp ? Did the results differ from what you want in some specific way?

Comment: i updated the post

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to clamp it.

```
public float Xspeed = 2.0f;
public float Yspeed = 2.0f;
float currentHeadRotationX;
float currentHeadRotationY;
public float minimumX = -20f;
public float maximumX = 20f;
public float minimumY = -45f;
public float maximumY = 45f;
public float damping = 2.0f;

void Start()
{

}
void Update()
{
    Vector2 mouseInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

    currentHeadRotationX = Mathf.Clamp(currentHeadRotationX - mouseInput.y * Xspeed, minimumY, maximumY);
    currentHeadRotationY = Mathf.Clamp(currentHeadRotationY + mouseInput.x  * Yspeed, minimumX, maximumX);

    var desiredRotQ = Quaternion.Euler(currentHeadRotationX, currentHeadRotationY, 0);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, desiredRotQ, Time.deltaTime * damping);
}
```